# How to add npm packages to docker images w/o remaking image or container?

Tags: node.js, docker, npm, dockerfile, npm-install

**Question:**
How can I install new packages and get docker image and container to recognize change, install and rerun w/o working developer interaction?

**package.json**: *notice that we have only 1 package*

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "node_modules/.bin/nodemon"
},
"dependencies": {
  "express": "4.15.4" 
}
```

**dockerfile**

```
FROM node:8.4.0

ENV HOME /var/www
WORKDIR ${HOME}

COPY server/package.json server/tsconfig.json server/nodemon.json $HOME/
RUN npm install
EXPOSE 8191
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

**Make image**:

```
docker build . -t testImage
```

**Run container**:

```
docker run -p 8191:8191 -v $(pwd)/server/src:/var/www/src testImage
```

Everything works as intended `[nodemon] starting`node ./src/index.js`

**The Problem:**

`npm install cors --save` *will add cors package*

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "node_modules/.bin/nodemon"
},
"dependencies": {
  "express": "4.15.4",
  "cors": "^2.8.4",
}
```

Problem is nothing will update in my docker container :(
I do not want the developer to have to remake the image or to have to rerun the a container:
`docker build . -t testImage`
`docker run -p 8191:8191 -v $(pwd)/server/src:/var/www/src testImage`

Comment: what about `docker exec <container id> npm install cors --save`?

Comment: do you have solution for this? please kindly share

Answer (score 0):

Take a look how ENTRYPOINT AND CMD works, if you want to use the same Dockerfile for production and development you can create a entrypoint script that if no arguments is provided run as production mode, if argument like development, run as development mode.

save development packages with --save-dev, so when running in development mode your container will install the dev dependencies.

Make sure your node_modules is at your .dockerignore,

Your dockerfile:

```
FROM node:8.4.0


ENV HOME /var/www
WORKDIR ${HOME}

COPY start_scrip.sh /start_scrip.sh

COPY server/package.json server/tsconfig.json server/nodemon.json $HOME/
RUN npm install
EXPOSE 8191
ENTRYPOINT ["/start_scrip.sh"]
```

A start_scrip.sh example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash


function development {
    npm install --dev # 
    npm start
}
function run_prod {
    #npm start command here
}


if [ $# -gt 0 ]
then
    if [ $1 == "development" ]
    then
        development
    else
        echo "Not a valid argument"
        exit 127
    fi
else
    run_prod
fi


exit 0
```

Make sure to chmod +x your script, so it can be executed inside the container.

To run in development mode:

```
run -p 8191:8191 -v $(pwd)/server/src:/var/www/src testImage development
```

Every time your developer add a new package in the workstation he should restart the container.